# How to find all arrays and not just the first occurance using find method in java script?

Tags: javascript, string

Here is my code:

```
const string = `1
00:01:46,356 --> 00:01:49,893
test test test test

2
00:01:50,794 --> 00:01:54,998
test test test red test test

3
00:01:55,199 --> 00:01:58,267
test test red`;

const match = st.split('\n\n').find((e) => e.includes('red'));


console.log(match);
```

the problem is it returns only the first occurance (the word "red" in 2nd sentence) while there is another "red" in the last sentence. What should I do to get all occurrences?

Comment: This is exactly what the `find` method does. It returns the first instance. You're probably looking for `filter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

> returns the value of the first element in the provided array that
> satisfies the provided testing function

Instead of find, you can use filter:

```
const match = string.split('\n\n').filter((e) => e.includes('red'));
```

```js
const string = `1
00:01:46,356 --> 00:01:49,893
test test test test

2
00:01:50,794 --> 00:01:54,998
test test test red test test

3
00:01:55,199 --> 00:01:58,267
test test red`;

const match = string.split('\n\n').filter((e) => e.includes('red'));
console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `filter` instead of `find`.

```js
const st = `1
00:01:46,356 --> 00:01:49,893
test test test test

2
00:01:50,794 --> 00:01:54,998
test test test red test test

3
00:01:55,199 --> 00:01:58,267
test test red`;

const match = st.split('\n\n').filter((e) => e.includes('red'));


console.log(match);
```